# How can I run python3 on my apache server by default?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mod-wsgi, mod-python

I am a beginner to Python here, and I am having an issue.

In my setup, I was using a PHP script to call the command line which in turn would execute a python script. Since then, I've discovered that I can run python directly.

My problem is that 2.6 is running when I call the script directly, and I need Python 3.3 to run instead.

After looking this up, I found I need to recompile `mod_python`, but then I found that I want to use `mod_wsgi` instead which is giving me a whole series of other errors like my python3 installation not having `--shared-libraries` when `make` was ran.

I am pulling my hair out trying to do such a seemingly simple task. Is there any direction someone can point me in? Again, I am a Python beginner. Any help is apprecited!

Comment: Are you actually calling your Python program from within PHP, using `system` or similar?  Or is the web server invoking the Python program directly?

Comment: Before, I was invoking with proc_open, but now I am invoking the python script directly via ajax